# Points inside, outside, and on a shape

Tags: c++

Given random points x (-250; 250) and y (-150; 150).Given a shape that is half rectangle and half rhombus.
How to find the number of points inside, outside, and on the shape?
I know how to find points separately in a rectangle and a rhombus.
Here is a photo of the shape (on the left)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGS52.jpg)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

struct Count {
    int k1 = 0, k2 = 0, k3 = 0;
};

void array_input ( Point *pp, Point* r) {
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    for (; pp < r; ++pp)    {
        (*pp).x = rand() % 501 - 250;
        (*pp).y = rand() % 301 - 150;
    }
    
    cout <<endl;
    
}

void array_output (struct Point *pp, Point *r) {
    for (; pp < r; ++pp)    {
        cout <<"x: " <<(*pp).x<<"\t"<< " y: "<<(*pp).y<<endl;
        
    }
}

Count number_of_points(struct Point *pp, Point *r)
{

    Count out;
    for (; pp < r; ++pp) {
        
        if (abs((*pp).x) > 150 || abs((*pp).y) > 100 ) {
            out.k3++;
        }
        
         else if (abs((*pp).x) < 150 || abs((*pp).y)< 100 ){
            out.k1++;
        }
        
        else {
            out.k2++;
        }
    }

    return out;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int n = 10;
    Point t[n];
    Count out;
    struct Point *pp;
    array_input(pp, pp+n);
    array_output(pp, pp+n);
    out = number_of_points (pp, pp+n);
    cout <<"Внутри: " << out.k1 << endl;
    cout <<"На фигуре: " << out.k2 << endl;
    cout <<"За пределами фигуры: " << out.k3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given your program has more than 10 lines, it's time to remove `using namespace std;`.

Comment: if you know how to find if the point is in a rectangle then you also know how to find it the point is inside half rectangle. Half rhombus is just a little more tricky.

Comment: Your problem is mathematical and not really related to a specific programming language.